# jQuery change property on load

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML

```
  <div id="navContainer">
    <ul>
      <li class="selected"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

And I want to change the top border of the li next to the selected one (in this case 'Services'). I have this jQuery but it does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($("#navContainer .selected").next().html()); // This alerts: <a href="#">Services</a>
  $("#navContainer .selected").next().css("border-top-color","#7d7d7d"); // This doesn't do anything
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're floating the list items, then they might not have the proper height to have the background color show up.  Have you tried manually changing the BG color using Firebug or a similar tool on the client site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to change the top border or the background color? Fix your question.

Your example works for me. Here's my full test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($("#navContainer .selected").next().html()); // This alerts: <a href="#">Services</a>
  $("#navContainer .selected").next().css("background-color","red");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="navContainer">
    <ul>
      <li class="selected"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The second element's background color turns red.

Comment: Sorry I changed it to background color to test if it would work but I forgot to change it back. Turned out to be the .js file.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, the background-color of the Services-LI is changed to red.

If you want to change the top-border, replace

```
.css("background-color", "red");
```

with

```
.css("border-top","solid 1px red");
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks ok to me, maybe your <a> link also defines a background-color which covers the one you set on the <li>, that could be why you cannot see anything.

I suggest you check the CSS styles using the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extensions for Firefox.

Comment: It turned out to be my .js file! I downloaded the production version and it works! I used the Visual Studio version before, also downloaded from jquery.com.

Sorry everyone, you're right there is nothing wrong with the code.